# How to trim the tail number of the file via shell script?

Tags: shell-script, rename, filenames

I have the files as below. There are four files in total:

`cert1.pem  chain1.pem  fullchain1.pem  privkey1.pem`

I want to trim the tail number of each file (`1` here). How do I use a shell script to handle it automatically? I am familiar with some commands, but I think I am not good at writing shell scripts to handle this batch processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the trailing number is a single digit, and they are all `.pem` files, you could use parameter expansion to strip the digit and extension, then replace the extension:

```
for file in cert1.pem  chain1.pem  fullchain1.pem  privkey1.pem
do
  mv "$file" "${file%%?.pem}.pem"
done
```

The parameter expansion works by removing the longest trailing match (`%%`) of any single character (`?`) followed by `.pem`; after that is done, we manually add back the `.pem` at the end.

Note that this would also rename files like `certX.pem` or `fullchain-.pem`, because the `?` character expands to any single character.

This is made safer in the above example because I've manually listed the files to rename. You could alternatively use something like:

```
for file in *1.pem
do
  mv "$file" "${file%%?.pem}.pem"
done
```

... which loops explicitly over files with `1.pem` at the end of their names.

### Setup:

```
$ ls
cert1.pem  chain1.pem  fullchain1.pem  privkey1.pem
```

### Execution:

```
$ for file in cert1.pem  chain1.pem  fullchain1.pem  privkey1.pem
  do 
    mv "$file" "${file%%?.pem}.pem"
  done
```

### Result:

```
$ ls
cert.pem  chain.pem  fullchain.pem  privkey.pem
```

Comment: It works. 
A comprehensible solution~

Comment: I have a question. I used "${file%%?.*}.pem", "${file%?.*}.pem" and "${file%?.pem}.pem". All of them are also workable. Why?
If I used ${file%%.*} or ${file%%.pem}, they are not workable. 
I think I am able to use asterisk to replace "pem" this word. I also know "%" it will start from the tail. It is different to "#" this symbol. I know "?" its meaning. But, why "?" is important in here for purpose to trim the tail?

Comment: Using `.*` means it would match (remove) any "extension" (characters after a period) instead of just "pem".  Using a single % is a good choice here, since you want to remove the shortest match, not the longest (%%). Your filenames didn't look like `file1.pem1.pem` so there's not a practical difference.

Comment: If I regard "?" as its purpose to parse its front word as none or something, am I right in here? I used ${file%.*}, ${file%%.*}, ${file%.pem} and ${file%%.pem}. The output shows up "are the same file".